# How do I make a post request work after using get_queryset?

Tags: python, django, post

I would like to have a list of a user's devices with a checkbox next to each one. The user can select the devices they want to view on a map by clicking on the corresponding checkboxes then clicking a submit button. I am not including the mapping portion in this question, because I plan to work that out later. The step that is causing problems right now is trying to use a post request.

To have the user only be able to see the devices that are assigned to them I am using the get_queryset method. I have seen a couple questions regarding using a post request along with the get_queryset method, but they do not seem to work for me. Using the view below, when I select a checkbox and then click submit, it looks like a post request happens followed immediately by a get request and the result is my table is empty when the page loads.

Portion of my views.py file:

```
class DeviceListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Device
    template_name = 'tracking/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'devices'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(who_added=self.request.user)       

    def post(self, request):
        form = SelectForm(request.POST)   
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Portions of my template:

```
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <form action="" method="post" name="devices_to_check"> 
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <table id="registered_devices" 
                        class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm" 
                        style="width:100%; border: 1px solid black; font-size: 10px">
                            <thead class="table-primary" 
                            style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid black">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>IMEI</th>
                                    <th>Label</th>
                                    <th>Device Type</th>
                                    <th>Group</th>
                                    <th>Subgroup</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Display</th>
                                </tr>    
                            </thead>
                            
                            <tbody>
                                {% for device in devices %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{device.imei}}</td>
                                        <td>{{device.label}}</td>
                                        <td style="text-transform:uppercase">{{device.device_type}}</td>
                                        <td>{{device.main_group}}</td>
                                        <td>{{device.subgroup}}</td>
                                        <td>{{device.description}}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center">
                                            <a href="{% url 'device-detail' device.id %}">i    </a>
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="{{device.imei}}" name="chk" 
                                            value="{{device.imei}}" onclick="show_info_icon()" 
                                            class="chckvalues"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick='selects()' 
                            value="Select All"/>  
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick='deSelect()' 
                            value="Deselect All"/>                            
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info">Show on Map</button>
                    </form>    
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're better off using a function based view with the typical "if request.method = POST" logic, this isn't really what the generic list view is for. (edits to snippet added)

```
@login_required
def device_list_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SelectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # if a request was posted and is valid, do your thing:
            # maybe your thing is to give your map view the device id
            # and render it
            # assuming your form has a field called device_id:
            context['device_id'] = form.device_id 
            return render(request, 'tracking/device_map.html', context)
   
    # either request method is not post or the form wasn't valid
    user_devices = Device.objects.filter(who_added=request.user)
    device_forms = []
    for i, device in enumerate(user_devices):
        form = SelectForm(instance=device, prefix=i)
        device_forms.append(form)
   context['device_forms'] = device_forms
  return render(request, 'tracking/home.html', context)
```

The key part here is the if-else logic of checking whether the request was POST or not, you'll need to tweak it based on exactly what you want to happen. It sounds like what you're really doing is creating one form from which you're pulling multiple device_ids. [This](https://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/) is a good reference for what's going on with the prefix bit and should help you decide whether to do things that way or with one form like you're trying.

Comment: I am following the majority of your logic. This is producing a list that is the name of all four of the fields separated by a semicolon as each of the items in the list. It is not rendering it as a form.

Comment: To be more clear, the output looks like this    [<SelectForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(imei;label;description;device_type)>, <SelectForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(imei;label;description;device_type)>, ... repeated for the same number of times as was enumerated.

Comment: What does your template now look like? You should have something like {% for form in device_forms %} {{ form}} {% endfor %}

Comment: Ahh. It is iterating over the form now and the submit button is giving a post request. I think I can work with it from here. It looks like a bunch of form fields, but I should be able to make it look like a table with checkboxes. Thanks for your help.